# The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type List<WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

//driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Test Selenium");
```

This is my coding. I am getting an error for `sendKeys()`.

I am using:

- windows 8 (64 bit)
- java  jdk 1.8
- selenium 3.4.0
- Firefox 53.0.2 (64 bit)

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

`driver.findElements` returns a `List` of `WebElements`; what you want to do is get an individual element from that `List`, and *then* call `sendKeys` on that element. The error you're getting is because `List<Element>` does not have a method `sendKeys(String)`.

For example:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"))
    .get(0)
    .sendKeys("Test Selenium");
```

Comment: It is working with your code but sendKeys() is not typing.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed that you have used `driver.findelements` instead of `driver.findelement`.

Use the latter one so that the `sendkeys` would work fine. Hope I have solved your query.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a local variable for WebElement and then variable.sendkeys(String) will work fine.
for example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("path").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
//here sendkeys will give error so, here is your answer:
WebElement var = driver.findElement(By.xpath("path"));
var.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

it should work fine.